# SSISDB Size (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am running into problems with my SSIS packages (executed by SQL Server Agent), specifically the size of the SSISDB.

Every time the job runs, it writes about 90k rows to internal.operation_messages alone.
99% of these entries are written by loops I am using within the package.
I already set recovery to simple on the SSISDB and reduced the retention window to 7 days. I also disabled any logging for the Projekt in Visual Studio.

I will probably have to reduce the retention window even further, since the package is supposed to run once an hour.

So my question is: Can I prevent SSIS from writhing this many rows in the first place? It seems like nothing I am doing has any impact on the amount of entries which are created.

The package is running on SQL Server 2014.

Cheers!

Comment: What [logging level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/598go.png) is the package set to run at in the agent job step?

Comment: I had absolutely no idea you could set the logging level in the agent job! I'll give it a shot tomorrow when I have access to the machine. Keeping my fingers crossed that this is available in SQL Server 2014!

Comment: That screenshot is from a 2012 instance I was using at the time, so it's there, @Stephan .

Comment: @Lanru: That did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by @Lanru works! Just set the logging level in the SQL Server Agent Step under "Configuration" -> "Advanced" -> "Logging Level". Thanks!